# AJAX Slideshow ASP.NET MVC 2 >> ToolkitScriptManager.cs Not Found!

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, ajaxcontroltoolkit, slideshow, toolkitscriptmanager

I'm trying to implement an AJAX Slideshow within an ASP.NET MVC 2 application.
This is the error I get running the .aspx page with the AJAX slideshow is:
(sorry it is in Italian...  'Ricerca di' means 'Search for', 'non esiste' means 'Not Found')

```
Individuazione origine di 'C:\Users\Stephen\Downloads\ajaxcontroltoolkit-a497357d78ce\AjaxControlToolkit_a497357d78ce\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManager.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {c1 d2 e2 8c cd 4b 65 11 35 53 7f f5 e3 3b 76 58}
Il file 'C:\Users\Stephen\Downloads\ajaxcontroltoolkit-a497357d78ce\AjaxControlToolkit_a497357d78ce\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManager.cs' non esiste.
Ricerca di 'C:\Users\Stephen\Downloads\ajaxcontroltoolkit-a497357d78ce\AjaxControlToolkit_a497357d78ce\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManager.cs' nei documenti di script...
Ricerca di 'C:\Users\Stephen\Downloads\ajaxcontroltoolkit-a497357d78ce\AjaxControlToolkit_a497357d78ce\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManager.cs' nei progetti.
Il file non è stato trovato in un progetto. >> File not Found.
```

It seems that the compiler is looking for `ToolkitScriptManager.cs` in a user folder?!?
Note that I downloaded the AJAX control toolbox from codeplex, pointing to the .NET 3.5 version, and I added the reference to the `AjaxControlToolbox.dll`.

Any suggestion? How can I handle this error?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

This link, [Using the Ajax control toolbox with jQuery (and ASP.NET MVC)](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=626), might give you some insight in how to solve your problem. From reading through the article, it seems that you might need to use the [script only files](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/16488) for the control toolkit to make things work out with the MVC framework.

I also found that Stephen Walther has a couple of [articles](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/23/asp-net-mvc-tip-36-create-a-popup-calendar-helper.aspx) on [how to use the Ajax Control Toolkit](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/24/asp-net-mvc-tip-37-create-an-auto-complete-text-field.aspx) with asp.net MVC.

Good luck and hope this information helps you some.